# DirtyCred: Free object through the vulnerability

Tags: use-after-free

I am studying an exploit of use-after-free called DirtyCred, it's a recent exploit of flaws released in August 2022 allowing a privilege escalation, through this [paper.](https://zplin.me/papers/DirtyCred.pdf)

And I have a lot of misunderstanding around this, and I haven't really found many references on the net since the exploit is recent.

Well, From the page 3 of the paper, I didn't understand what does the ***Step 2: free the ﬁle object through the vulnerability.*** exactly mean, we do allocate memory for opening a file through a function, so how a uaf flaw(defined in other function) will be able to free it? in other words, uaf frees memory that it allocates itself and not that other allocates.
[image: Schema]

I am studying this exploit through [Cve-2022-2588](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2022-2588) which is simply a use after free found in a function in net module withing kernel linux.